# how to manually insert primary key while inserting a row - EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

I am using MVC 4 with Visual studio 2012. I want to insert primary key while creating row. My tables as as :

```
<Table("StudentRec")> _
Public Class StudentRec
   <Key()> _
  Public Property ErNo as Integer
  Public Property Name as String
  Public Property Branch as String
  Public Property Course as String
End Class

<Table("Attendance")> _
Public Class Attendance
   <Key()> _
  Public Property ErNo as Integer
  Public Property Present as Integer
  Public Property Leaves as Integer
End Class
```

My Action Controller is :

```
<HttpPost()> _
<AllowAnonymous()> _
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()> _
    Function CreateUser(ByVal Modl As StudentRec) As ActionResult
        Try
            Using dbb As New UsersContext
                Dim Erno As Integer = dbb.StudentRec_.Add(Modl).ErNo
                dbb.SaveChanges()

                Dim Attnd As New Attendance
                Attnd.ErNo = Erno  ' Not Working, Erno is automatically Set '
                Attnd.Leaves = 0
                Attnd.Present = 0

                dbb.Attendance_.Add(Attnd)
                dbb.SaveChanges()

            End Using
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        Catch ex As Exception
            TempData("Errs") = ex.Message
            Return View(Modl)
        End Try
        Return View(Modl)
    End Function
```

How to Manually Set Primary key to table Attendance, with respect to Primary Key of table StudentRec ?

Comment: Apparently you have a 1:1 association, so `StudentRec` should have an `Attendance` property, and you should set this property.

Comment: could you please give me an example code for that ? So that i can know how it should be done...